# How to automate clickable false element using UI automator in Android application

Tags: appium

I am working to automate android application using an open source tool name called appium. This tool uses android UIautomator  to automate native element. We are facing an issue like if some of the elements are set with clickable as false, how to click or automate these elements.

Any help from you is higly appericated.

Thanks
Manikandan

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the clickable value by the following way:

`Boolean satus=driver.findElement(locator_of_element).getAttribute("clickable").equals("false");
if(status)
{
//Do Some Stuff
}`

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to access your elements with the ID specified in the Android res layout.

Only I'm not sure if the onclick handlers are fired, if clickable is set to false, you should try it.